# Как вывести данные модели в шаблон Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я новичок в django поэтому прошу помощи у спецов
Имеется 2 модели

```
class Musican(models.Model):
    band = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    albums = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
    """
        String for representing the Model object.
    """
        return self.albums

class Soung(models.Model):
    albums = models.ForeignKey(Musican,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    soungs = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.soungs
```

Суть такова, первая таблица это группа и альбом, вторая это композиции определенного альбома.Вот я не могу понять как в шаблоне вывести так чтобы кликая по альбому открывался список песен данного альбома

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вам бы нормализацию данных провести. Вот так например:

```
class Band(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    # other data ...


class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='albums')


# бтв правильно Song
class Soung(models.Model):
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='songs')
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='songs')
```

Теперь, что косается того, как вывести все песни в альбоме, прежде всего прочитайте про [Model Field references](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/), в особенности про reverse relation.

Так вот имeя альбом, вы сможете найти все песни, которые на него "ссылаются", таким способом `album.songs.all()`, что потребует допольнительный запрос к бд. В темплэйте делается абсолютно так же. А что косается того, чтобы показывалось по клику, то это уже думаю вне топика Django и Python.

```
{% for song in album.soungs.all %}
...
{% endfor %}
```